# Forcing the elements to stay within the constraint boundary

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Good afternoon, I'm trying to place a textview and an icon on the right side, with the text on the right, but I can't do this with the constraint layout, they could help me how to do it without the text breaking out

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_constraint_foto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_foto"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_foto">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/appCompatTextView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
                android:text="Selecione uma imagemsaddsasdasdasdadsasdasdaasddddd"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cselect_image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzGij.png)

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because you have set `android:layout_width="wrap_content"` for text view.
As you want text view and image view aligned left to right, with above approach width of text view is more than available space hence some part of it goes outside screen. You can follow below steps to fix this :

1. set textview `android:layout_width="0dp"`
2. set `app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.8"` for textview. With this we ensure that textview will cover max 80% of the width (so text will not go outside screen). I have used 80% here, you can adjust it as you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can select all elements inside ConstraintLayout then apply "Clear all constraints" from Design Tab, then drag and drop your elements as your needed area( you can apply BaseLine constraint between textview and your ImageView). Then finally apply "infer Constraint" button.

Though directly you can put these code inside your ConstraintLayout

```
   <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/appCompatTextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
        android:text="Selecione uma imagemsaddsasdasdasdadsasdasdaasddddd"
        android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cselect_image"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/appCompatTextView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/appCompatTextView2" />
```

Output is -
[image]